# Copy an object with relations in which there is a Sortable object throws an Duplicate Entry error

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

In an old projet using `symfony 1.4` There are an object `Product` linked to other objects such as `Translation` `ProductPlatform` ...

**What I want to do is `copy` the Product object with all its relations.**

Pretty simple with `$product->copy(true)` `BUT`

It doesn't copy the relations, so i need to do :

```
  $this->loadReference('Translation');
  $this->loadReference('ProductPlatforms');

  foreach ($this->ProductPlatforms as $platform) {
    $platform->loadReference('Translation');
  }

  $newProduct = $this->copy(true);
  $newProduct->save();

  return $newProduct;
```

The throwed error is this :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-131' for key 'product_platform_position_sortable_idx'
```

What I don't understand is the following requests :

```
SELECT p.id AS p__id, p.position AS p__position FROM product_platform p 
WHERE (p.product_id = 'EndNote (copie)') ORDER BY p.position desc LIMIT 1;
----
INSERT INTO product_platform (publish_configuration, product_id, platform_id, position) 
VALUES ('1', '131', '1', '1')
```

And then, it reinsert, for another object, the same position :

```
INSERT INTO product_platform (publish_configuration, product_id, platform_id, position) 
VALUES ('1', '131', '3', '1');
```

Why there is, instead of an ID, the Name of my object in the `Where` clause `WHERE (p.product_id = 'EndNote (copie)')`. **I think this is the reason it tries to insert the same value.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's a bug with the Sortable behaviour, we sent a PR :

https://github.com/bshaffer/csDoctrineActAsSortablePlugin/pull/25